# Writing a small script to extract MS Exchange audit logs in .csv format

Tags: windows, powershell

**Background**

I'm using MS Exchange 2013 in my environment, and have a separate siem box which analyze logs produced by different systems (i.e exchange). The logs for Exchange are internally stored and can however be extracted such as

> ```
> Get-MailboxAuditLog -Identity test-mailbox-1 -LogonTypes
> Admin,Delegate –ShowDetails -StartDate mm/dd/2014 -EndDate mm/dd/2014
> | Export-Csv “c:\test-Audit-Results.csv”
> ```

**Steps taken so far**

- Enabling audit on Exchange
- Got the command Google which needs to put in a script (above)

**My requirements (in algorithm)**

1. check presence of properties file with last collect time.
2. If file is absent query the data from some period of time before till the current moment:

   1. `Search-AdminAuditLog -StartDate (get-date).adddays(-30) -EndDate (get-date) | Export-Csv "c:\admin-results-temp.csv"`
   2. remember "get-date" value to properties file
   3. copy "admin-results-temp.csv" file contents to the final file  to be forwarder by ALE
3. **If file is present:**

   1. Get last collect time calculate difference in time from present time. If time-difference is more then 1 hours ...pull the log again
   2. execute Search-AdminAuditLog with StartDate = date from props file, EndDate = current
   3. remember current time to the props file
   4. copy "admin-results-temp.csv" file contents to the final file  to be forwarder by ALE
4. You can clean up final file  once a week to avoid over-grow. ALE will forward it from the beginning at that case.
5. Schedule the script/code described above to run each minute
6. Configure ALE in a File Forwarder mode to send  file

Note: On part of ALE that part is already automated. No need for file-forwarding required.

I want the above algorithm in a power shell script.

Current code:

```
<#

#>

#...................................
# Variables
#...................................

$check_collect_last

#...................................
# Initialize
#...................................

#Set recipient scope
$2007snapin = Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
if ($2007snapin)
{
    $AdminSessionADSettings.ViewEntireForest = 1
}
else
{
    $2010snapin = Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
    if ($2010snapin)
    {
        Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true
    }
}


#If no filename specified, generate report file name with random strings for uniqueness

    $source=c:\results-audit        
    $check_last = (ls $source).LastWriteTime



#...................................
# Script
#...................................

#Add dependencies
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Get the mailbox list

$mailboxcount = $mailboxes.count
$i = 0

$mailboxdatabases = @(Get-MailboxDatabase)

$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem C:\Mail-audit-results | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo.count #Returns the count of all of the files in the directory

If $directoryInfo.count -eq 0

{

#Loop through mailbox list
foreach ($mb in $mailboxes)
{
    $i = $i + 1
    $pct = $i/$mailboxcount * 100    

    Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting audit details for Mail admin" -Status "Processing mailbox $i of $mailboxcount - $mb" -PercentComplete $pct

     $Startdate=((Get-Date).adddays(-30)).ToShortDateString()
     $Enddate=(Get-Date).ToShortDateString()
     $check_collect_last=Get-Date -format HH:mm:ss


    $auditAdmin_search = $mb | Search-MailboxAuditLog -Identity $i -LogonTypes Admin,Delegate –ShowDetails -StartDate  $Startdate -EndDate $Enddate | Export-Csv “c:\Mail-audit-results\Temp-Audit-Results.csv”   


   #appending file to final audit csv file
   [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\Mail-audit-results\Temp-Audit-Results.csv") | Out-File c:\Mail-audit-results\Final-mail-admin.csv -Append -Encoding Unicode 

}

}

else
    # if difference between last collect time and present is more then #1 hours collect logs in cycle / hrs
$Now = Get-Date -format HH:mm:ss
    $check_collect_last = New-TimeSpan $check_collect_last $Now

    if ($check_collect_last.Hours -gt 1) 
    {

    foreach ($mb in $mailboxes)
{

$i = $i + 1
    $pct = $i/$mailboxcount * 100    

    Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting audit details for Mail admin" -Status "Processing mailbox $i of $mailboxcount - $mb" -PercentComplete $pct
     $Startdate=((Get-Date).ToShortDateString()
     $Enddate=(Get-Date).ToShortDateString()

    $auditAdmin_search = $mb | Search-MailboxAuditLog -Identity $i -LogonTypes Admin,Delegate –ShowDetails -StartDate   -EndDate $Enddate | Export-Csv “c:\Mail-audit-results\Temp-Audit-Results.csv
    $check_collect_last=$Startdate

}

    }

    else
    return 0
```

This is my first powershell script.  I'd appreciate it if someone can suggest/review if possible, especially in regard to date functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple syntax errors. As a start, I would fix those. Also, fix up the indenting to make it easier to see what is going on. Which editor are you using? You could try using the PowerShell ISE. It will show you some of your errors with red wiggly lines.

As a general strategy, I would suggest writing your code step-by-step. Get one thing working before moving on to the next. Break your code up into functions.